# How to access a saved photo inside simulator on IOS 7

Tags: ios

I had drag and drop a photo inside the `IOS simulator` and then saved it inside `Safari`. This photo got saved in `/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0001.JPG`.

When I run the app using `UIImagePickerController` I cannot see any photos, just the message: `No Photos or Videos. You can sync photos and videos onto your iPhone using iTunes`.

Is there anything different I have to do to access that photo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in the simulator, go to safari, then search an image.
Long press that image and a popup will show. Choose Save Image. Now the image is saved in your saved photos album.

When in the app, open the ImagePicker like this :

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Be sure to include `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` for the mediaType (if you want photos only, without videos).

(if it's an iPad app it will be a little different, you will need to use UIPopoverController).

You should be able to see that image you saved.

Good Luck.

Comment: I get the following crash: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 0'. Instead of kUTTypeImage I use @"jpg".

Comment: Did you import `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` ?
I wouldn't recommend using "JPG". You might want to see different formats like PNG or BMP.

Comment: Do you have MobileCoreServices framework in your project?
If not, can you add it?

Comment: Ok, I have also added to my project. It was missing, but it still crash

Comment: I have added back (NSString*)kTTypeImage, and now it doesn't crash, but I still can't see any photo

Comment: And when you go into the simulator's photo library you see photos?

Comment: Can you clean and restart your app?

Comment: No, I don't. But I save it from Safari

Comment: Can you make the save again? Long press on the image and then "Save Image" You should be able to see it in the library afterwards

Comment: Good news. After restarting Xcode and the Simulator now I can see the photo when I run my app.